# How to put attributes of FlowFile into its JSON content?

Tags: python, json, apache-nifi

I use `ExecuteScript` processor and Python language to write a script.

I want to pass two attributes (`eventid` and `reason`) of FlowFile into its JSON content as the parameter:value pair. The value of `eventid` is string, while the value of `reason` is integer. I tried to use `flowFile.getAttribute('eventid')`, but it fails.

What is the correct way?

```
def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):
        text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        obj = json.loads(text)
        dt = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')

        newObj = {
            "EventId": str(parse(flowFile.getAttribute('eventid'))),
            "EventType": self.getEventType(dt,obj),
            "EventReason": flowFile.getAttribute('reason')
        }
        outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(newObj, indent=4).encode('utf-8')))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
session.commit()
```

Comment: I don't really know python, but does the callback actually have access to flowFile which is obtained outside the callback?

Comment: @BryanBende: How can I then access it? This is the question. I want just to copy the content of two attributes into the JSON content of FlowFile. There should be some way to do it because it's a common task. Maybe some processor for this?

Comment: If you want to overwrite the content with a new JSON, then you can use ReplaceText and set the Replacement Value to a JSON string like { "EventId" : ${eventid} }

Comment: @BryanBende: No, I want to append the current content. i am trying to use ExtractText->AttributesToJSON. However, I don't know how to extract fields from JSON content using ExtractText. For example, in the content I have something like `{"eventid":"123","reason":2,"data":[{...},{...}]}`. I want to put `eventid` and `reason` into attributes. Then the problem will be solved.

Comment: If you want to extract eventid and reason then use EvaluateJsonPath with the destination set to flow-file attributes, and add two properties with the json paths to extract like eventid = $.eventid

Comment: @BryanBende: Sorry, I have not mentioned one important aspect. In my real data `reason` and `eventid` and not scalar values. They are JSON substrings like `"eventid": {}`. Therefore `EvaluateJsonPath` does not work for me. It gives errors. I must probably use `ExtractText`, but cannot write a regex expression.

Comment: @BryanBende: Oh, I had to select json as result in EvaluateJsonPath... Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use EvaluateJsonPath with Destination set to flow-file attributes and Return Type set to JSON. Then you can add properties for each JSON path to extract like:

```
eventid = $.eventid
```

Comment: The only issue is that `eventid` is a Json string that contains `\`, e.g. `{"eventid":"[{\"id1\":\"t234\",\"id2\":10},{...}]`

Comment: contains `\`. how can I get a string without these symbols?

Comment: after EvaluateJsonPath you can use UpdateAttribute to apply expression language functions, there is a replace function